# How can I add a text under a FAB in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an app for android and I need to put a text under a FAB (Floating Action Button) like so:

[image]

but every time I'm trying to use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout with it, the FAB just sets to a random location and it's not where I need it to be.

I can't post all of my code for this layout because it has some details that I can't share (I'm under contract and this is not a public project). So if you need anything specific let me know and I'll find a way to share it without revealing anything.

EDIT: I need it to be a FAB because after I click on something on the layout it should look like this:
[FAB after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZQGQ.png)

And if you click on the picture, it goes to a different page

Comment: Interesting.. I think you might have to just create your own fab (don't use the fab class).

Comment: Did you try to put a TextView under it using a Relative Layout and the layoutBelow attribute with the FAB id as a value ?

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to make a view that looks the way you want it to.

Comment: depending on what you're doing with the fab (whether you're doing animations or something) @AlexandreMartin's suggestion is probably what you want.

Comment: Add your codes to questions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CoordinatorLayout to set the position of FAB?

Here's an example how you can do that.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main_content"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <-- PUT HERE YOUR TEXTVIEW -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT: To change anchorGravity

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(xxxx);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Comment: It works for my first step but is there a way to set the "layout_anchorGravity" in the code dynamically while the app is running?

Comment: If I understood correctly, it changes the anchor ID, I need to change the anchorGravity from: android:layout_gravity="center" to: android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"